# Slider value not working for Accessibility - iOS8

Tags: ios8, slider, accessibility, voiceover, uiaccessibility

I have a slider and I want to limit its value to range from 1 to 5. I have set the min and max values on both Interface Builder and in codes but am currently facing two main issues.

1) The value doesn't change (keeps saying value 1).

2) On top of that, I am also unable to adjust the value of the slider when VoiceOver accessibility mode is on. The value keeps reading it as 1, even though on the surface, it may be on value 3/4/5.

Here are some of my codes to implement the slider in Swift. I am not sure what is the problem here with this. Any help is appreciated!

```
@IBOutlet weak var busSlider: UISlider!

override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated)
    busSlider.minimumValue = 1
    busSlider.maximumValue = 5
}

override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool) {
    busSlider.accessibilityValue = NSNumberFormatter.localizedStringFromNumber(busSlider.value, numberStyle: NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle)
    busSlider.accessibilityLabel = NSLocalizedString("\(Int(busSlider.value))", comment: "")
}

override func accessibilityIncrement() {
    busSlider.value++
    busSlider.sendActionsForControlEvents(UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    busSlider.accessibilityValue = NSNumberFormatter.localizedStringFromNumber(busSlider.value, numberStyle: NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle)
    busSlider.accessibilityLabel = NSLocalizedString("\(Int(busSlider.value))", comment: "")
}

override func accessibilityDecrement() {
    busSlider.value--
    busSlider.sendActionsForControlEvents(UIControlEvents.ValueChanged)
    busSlider.accessibilityValue = NSNumberFormatter.localizedStringFromNumber(busSlider.value, numberStyle: NSNumberFormatterStyle.DecimalStyle)
    busSlider.accessibilityLabel = NSLocalizedString("\(Int(busSlider.value))", comment: "")
}
```

*On the side note: I actually have 2 sliders on the same screen but belonging to different sections. The first slider reads the value in percentage (speak rate), and this slider needs to read the value in integer (number of stops).

Comment: where did u set the accessibility label ?

Comment: Hi Mr.T, I have edited my codes above! (:

Comment: you need to change the accebilityvalue everytime you change a value. Keep that in viewdidappear and see!!!

Comment: Hi Mr.T, the value got updated now, however, the 2nd problem still persists. Now, it reads the current value that it had started from (e.g. 3), but after swiping down (to decrease to value 2), it still reads as 3. And I am still unable to increase the value (swipe up).

Comment: when are you calling accessibilityDecrement ?

Comment: Ohhh, do I have to implement the gesture method as well?

Comment: u need to change the accessibility label on both increment and decrement methods.

Comment: the slider should work with one finger swipe up and down !!!

Comment: Hi Mr. T, I'm not really sure what you mean but could you see my edited codes again? It still doesn't work by the way, I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Moreover, it doesn't seem like the `accessibilityIncrement()` and `accessibilityDecrement()` methods are being called when I swipe up or down.